# How to add and remove Multiple Sender Addresses to Azure Email Communication Service programmatically

Tags: c#, azure-communication-services

We can add multiple email sender's addresses after configuring custom domain (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/add-multiple-senders):

[image: adding sender]

Now, I want to do it programmatically with some of the SDKs. Is there any possibilities to do that?

Comment: See following example : https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/communication/Azure.Communication.Email/samples/Sample4_SendEmailToMultipleRecipients.md#send-an-email-message-to-multiple-recipients

Comment: @jdweng it is example of sending email, not adding email sender address

Comment: Everything is in the example!!!  var emailRecipients = new EmailRecipients(toRecipients, ccRecipients, bccRecipients); var emailMessage = new EmailMessage(
    senderAddress: "<Send email address>" // The email address of the domain registered with the Communication Services resource
    emailRecipients,
    emailContent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/add-multiple-senders-mgmt-sdks?pivots=programming-language-csharp

```
string subscriptionId = "";
string resourceGroupName = "";
string emailServiceName = "";
string domainName = "";
string emailAddressToAdd = "no-replay";
ArmClient client = new(new DefaultAzureCredential());

ResourceIdentifier senderUsernameResourceId = SenderUsernameResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, emailServiceName, domainName, emailAddressToAdd);
SenderUsernameResource senderUsernameResource = client.GetSenderUsernameResource(senderUsernameResourceId);

SenderUsernameResourceData data = new()
{
    Username = emailAddressToAdd,
    DisplayName = "No Replay",
};
senderUsernameResource.Update(WaitUntil.Completed, data);
```